# VBScript SVCHOST container Detection

Tags: vbscript

I m building a vb script that will connect to each computer and the goal is to detect an exe that runs inside `SVCHOST` process.

How can i detect that if this exec is present inside `SVCHOST`, and if so terminate the `SVCHOST` process that contains in this exec ?

Thank you

Comment: What is your aim ? please describe more in details !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can begin with this code :

```
Option Explicit
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

Dim objWMI,colObjects,MyProcess,Process,TheProcess,DetectionProgram,MyPID
TheProcess = "svchost.exe"
DetectionProgram = "DcomLaunch"
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colObjects = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process where Caption='"& TheProcess &"'")

For Each Process in colObjects
    MyProcess = MyProcess & Process.CommandLine & vbcrlf & "PID = " & Process.ProcessID & vbcrlf
Next

Wscript.Echo MyProcess  

For Each Process in colObjects
    If InStr(1,Ucase(Process.CommandLine),UCase(DetectionProgram)) >= 1 Then
        MyPID = Process.ProcessID
        wscript.echo "PID = " & MyPID
        Call Kill(MyPID)
    End If
Next

'****************************************************
Sub Kill(PID)
    Dim Ws,Command,Execution
    Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /PID "& PID &""
    Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,True)
    Set Ws = Nothing
End Sub 
'****************************************************
```

Comment: The problem is what is inside SVCHOST, how to select that? That code will only give me the Process name... SVCHOST contains other process, and the exe is inside of one SVCHOST, I need to identify that exact SVCHOST to select it and terminate it